# Green's function for Laplace operator in a conformally flat metric?

Tags: integration, riemannian-geometry, conformal-geometry, laplacian, greens-function

Given the Laplace–Beltrami operator $\nabla^2$, does there exists a closed form for the greens function $G$ such that $\nabla_x^2G(x,y)=-\delta(x,y)$, and
$$
\nabla_x^2\iiint_{y^3}G(x,y)f(y)dy^3=-f(x) \ , \
$$
if we know that the metric defining $\nabla^2$ is conformally flat?
$$
\nabla^2 \phi = |g|^{-1/2} \partial_\mu\left( |g|^{1/2} g^{\mu\nu} \partial_\nu\right)\phi 
$$

Comment: Is $\nabla^2$ the standard Laplacian operator?

Comment: @Dr.MV Its the Laplace–Beltrami operator.

Comment: I call that the surface Laplacian.

Comment: @What is a surface Laplacian?

Comment: Here  is a paper for the surface Laplacian for a toroidal surface. http://rspa.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/royprsa/469/2149/20120479.full.pdf

Comment: A presentation on the same Green's function.            http://www.birs.ca/workshops/2015/15w5052/files/Green_Banff.pdf

Comment: It is the Lapalce-Beltrami operator.

Comment: @Dr.MV I assume that this paper is specific to 2D. I am struggling with 3D.

Comment: The surface is a 2-parameter family.  Do you have surfaces in hyper space?

Comment: You may find this useful.  http://www.mis.mpg.de/fileadmin/jjost/green_functions_and_conformal_geo.pdf   My first instinct is that you won't find a nice formula because the Green's function can be written in terms of the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of the Laplacian and there's no nice way of relating the eigenthings of two metrics if all you know is that they're conformally equivalent. Miraculous cancellation is not out of the question, though.

Comment: @Dr.MV I don't think I have surfaces in hyperspace, however I think you're suggesting to express the problem in a higher dimension and then curve it?

Comment: i think 2D could be possible, because conformal  constraints so much stronger then in higher dimension. in the higher dimension i don't think so..